# Mailchimp: Retrieve all newstletter/lists from one member

Tags: mailchimp

Hi is it possible in Mailchimp, with one call to retrieve all lists where a member is subscribed to?

Answer (score 0):

In our organization we have multiple newsletter lsts, I would like to retrieve all subscription with one mailchimp call and not individual calls like:

```
https://us3.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/[newsletter 1]/members/[email]
https://us3.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/[newsletter 2]/members/[email]
https://us3.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/[newsletter 3]/members/[email]
```